# Python UTF8 encoding with arabic

Tags: python, django, utf-8

I have a encoding problem, When I try to crawl youtube (arabic channel) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*- 
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import requests, lxml, re
from lxml import html

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/user/aljazeerachannel/videos?view=0")
        root = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)

        for data in root.xpath('.//*[@id="branded-page-body"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span/span/a'):
            print data.text
```

The result is :

```
[root@vmi9105 buzzbal]# python manage.py youtube

        Ø§ÙØªØ®Ø§Ø¨Ø§Øª Ø§ÙÙØ¬Ø§ÙØ³ Ø§ÙØ¨ÙØ¯ÙØ© ÙÙ Ø³ÙØ·ÙØ© Ø¹ÙÙØ§Ù
```

Comment: did you try encoding root to utf-8?

Comment: when i try a encoding root :
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-24: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: hmm i somtimes have this problems with German too. How about encode.('cp1252')? Is that working?

Answer (score 2):

try this it sloved my problem in python:

```
f"{yourString}".encode('latin-1').decode("utf-8")
```